# Where's the script located? Localhost or on the Server?

Tags: php, localhost

Like many programmers I have a server where I host my scripts, and a localhost where I make them. Is there in PHP a **secure** way to let the script tell the difference between them? SERVER_NAME works, but can be injected, so isn't **secure**. Does someone have a solution? (Non-Static Solution preferable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`php_uname('n')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) to return the current host's name, and use that to decide which environment you're in, but there isn't much benefit to this over simply defining your environment in a config file.  You only have to do so once per installation.

I personally find the easiest way is to define an `ENVIRONMENT` symbol as `'development'`, `'testing'`, or `'production'` in a config file which is excluded from version control. I include that file in some part of my project and then `assert` that the `ENVIRONMENT` symbol is defined. The program will tank if I've checked out a copy of my project and forgot to create the config file or specify the environment within it.

You could combine these approaches to define `ENVIRONMENT` based on host name.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to check the IP of `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`, or just have a config setting indicate which is which..

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Apache each [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost) will have a specific set of hostnames and aliases defined for it. This is the name you'll retrieve from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and is essentially the data from the Host: HTTP header

The only time you might need further checks for this is when your vhost is the default vhost, and so fields requests for domains not associated with host vhosts, or your vhost uses wildcards for the [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername) or [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias).

Comment: HTTP_HOST is send by the browser. I was talking about a secure solution! HTTP headers are not secure;)

Comment: @Kevin that is only half true. If I send a totally incorrect `HTTP_HOST`, Apache will (should) not serve the correct virtual host.

Comment: You should not trust Apache when you're not hosting it yourself. Who knows how the configuration is set?

Comment: But if you don't control the server, why are you trusting *that*?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost')
{
   // it is  local host
}
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. This solution is not secure, because users can change the HTTP_HOST value

Comment: I thought you have the only access to the server. I think this is a shared hosting environment. I would use a config file to do this, and while syncing local and remote host this config file can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

create a file somewhere out of the www . the do a if(file_exists('YOUR FILE PATH')) ...

give it a strange name . in the c:\ if ur on windows or in the /usr/home/ if u are on linux

Comment: I would A) not give it a strange name and B) not place it outside of your project. You're just confusing things needlessly.

Comment: the difference between webservers and you localhost is that the webserver has no games installed on it (for example) , the hardware , and any other data that is not needed on the webserver (your personal files) so it would be a nice idea to create some personal file that when it exists this means ur in the localhost , otherwise it means its the server,and no one can create such a file on the server specially if it's out somewhere in a read-only folder that is not accessible by apache or whatever service . if anyone could create the file ,means he has access to the server , means security gone!

Answer (score 0):

Because my development and production paths are always different, I usually tend to check `dirname(__FILE__)` against an array of possible values.

Depending on which value I end up with, the correct config file will be loaded.